# What's a good use case for using .defer() besides of System.currentTimeMillis()

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I've got the following code:

```
Single<Player> createPlayerSingle() {
    Integer playerId = Random.nextInteger();
    return playersDao.createSingle(id);
}
```

I was told I should add `Single.defer()`.

```
Single<Player> createPlayerSingle() {
    return Single.defer(() -> {
        Integer playerId = Random.nextInteger();
        return playersDao.createSingle(id);
    }
}
```

The idea was that if we create another subscription to `createPlayerSingle()` we won't generate new id (basically we'll reuse the old one).

I can't understand why it's the case. Should we add `defer` to every function that begins with some sync block of code then?

```
Single<T> methodSingle() {
    return Single.defer(() -> {
        Integer id = Random.nextInteger(); // sync block of code
        ....
        return dao.createSingle(id);
    });
}
```

I do understand what `defer` does (it executes lambda for every subscriber, e.g., if we put `System.currentTimeMillis()` inside of the lambda we'll receive 2 different values for 2 subscriptions in oppose to 1 same value if we use `.just` or `.fromCallable` instead of `.defer`).

Should we put `defer` here as well when we take a property from the argument? It doesn't make sense to me (even if we subscribe to the result of that method the 2nd time we'll call it with some arguments).

```
Single<T> methodSingle(Object object) {
        return Single.defer(() -> {
            Integer id = object.id; // sync block of code
            ....
            return dao.createSingleFrom(id);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write a method that returns a `Single` (or any other of the RxJava stream types) you are returning something that can be subscribed to many times, possibly concurrently.

`Defer` is a tremendously powerful (but simple) operator that allows you to define *per-subscription* state. For example if you wanted special behaviour for the first emission:

```
Observable<Integer> numbers = Observable.just(1, 2, 3);
Observable<Integer> numbers2 = 
    Observable.defer(() -> {
        boolean[] first = new boolean[] {true};
        return numbers.doOnNext(x -> {
            if (first[0]) {
                System.out.println("first=" + x);
                first[0] = false;
            } else {
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        });
    });
numbers2.subscribe();
numbers2.subscribe();
```

produces

```
first=1
2
3
first=1
2
3
```

Re this code:

```
Single<T> methodSingle(Object object) {
    return Single.defer(() -> {
        Integer id = object.id; // sync block of code
        ....
        return dao.createSingleFrom(id);
    });
}
```

If `object` is immutable then this is pointless and you could have left out the `defer` as you suspect.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime I feel the need to mess around with .create(), I realize it is simple with .defer(). The .defer() prep code is generally the one launching queries, and shoving the result in a Observable.just().